# VBA macro to capture multiple SQL result sets

Tags: sql-server, vba

I've used VBA macros in relation to SQL server a few times but they've always been a single "select" statement or calling a stored procedure that returned a single result set. Now I find myself writing a macro that will call a stored procedure but the stored procedure returns multiple result sets. Is it possible for a macro to capture each SQL result set and put it on a different worksheet? Any examples and/or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

That's pretty easily done with .NextRecordset.

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, success As Boolean
success = getAResultWith2Recordsets(rs)
If success = False Then
    MsgBox "Unable to records, no data"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set Me.Recordset = rs ' for example on a report
    Set SecondRs = New ADODB.Recordset ' create empty recordset
    Set SecondRs = rs.NextRecordset ' assign it the next batch result
    Set rs = Nothing
End If
```

And so on. This is only an example, you'll find all necessary info in the manual to [.nextRecordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), e.g. how to iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

YMMV; but in most cases it goes against "best practices" to return multiple recordsets per query because they are returned in ordinal order (0, 1, 2) so it's not self-documenting.  However, assuming that you are writing this and know the order of recordsets, something like this would work.

```
'' ---> Assuming you have logic to execute SQL and place results into a DataSet <--- ''

dt = ds.tables(0)
if dt.rows.count  > 0 then

    '' This datatable as datarows ''
    '' apply logic relevant to specific worksheet ''


end if

dt = ds.tables(1)
if dt.rows.count  > 0 then

    '' This datatable as datarows ''
    '' apply logic relevant to specific worksheet ''


end if

dt = ds.tables(2)
if dt.rows.count  > 0 then

    '' This datatable as datarows ''
    '' apply logic relevant to specific worksheet ''


end if
dt.dispose
ds.dispose
```

**---> You could also iterate the datatable collection; but this isn't exactly elegant.**

```
dim i as integer = 0
for i = 0 to ds.tables.count-1
    dt = ds.tables(i)
    if dt.rows.count> 0 then

        '' Apply worksheet logic here ''

    end if
next
```

This code is untested.